# How do I detect only the black rectangle that appears in the reference image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image: Original Image]

I need to detect only the black rectangle that appears there, but for some reason my code does not detect it but it does detect many other things.

```py
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('vision.png') #read image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
Blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),1) #apply blur to roi
Canny=cv2.Canny(Blur,10,50) #apply canny to roi

#Find my contours
contours =cv2.findContours(Canny,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]

cntrRect = []
for i in contours:
        epsilon = 0.05*cv2.arcLength(i,True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(i,epsilon,True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            cv2.drawContours(img,cntrRect,-1,(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.imshow('Image Rect ONLY',img)
            cntrRect.append(approx)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How do I detect only the black rectangle that appears in the image

[image]

But this code detect more rectangles and I don't want whis, but I only want detect the black countour rectangle
[image]

Comment: Please, post the original unprocessed image.

Comment: @stateMachine I have updated my question and incorporate the original image

Comment: Don't use Canny. The image has high-frequency textures and Canny is a high pass filter that enhances the high-frequency components. All the noise you see are high-frequency intensities changing color rapidly. The square seems to have a nice black border, my suggestion would be to directly threshold the image and try to isolate the black color of the square with some morphology to close the square edges. Then, maybe a flood-fill at the four corners of the image, the goal would be to filter everything except the actual square. You'd end up with a white square (the biggest object) and some noise.

Comment: @stateMachine without Canny it's even more difficult

Comment: if you need mostly straight edges (and more simple things like thresholing dont work), use lineSegmentDetector. If you need any edges, you can use canny, but apply an appropriate low-pass filter before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

Threshold the image. Then use morphology to fill out the rectangle. Then get the largest contour and draw on the input.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("black_rectangle_outline.png")

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply close morphology
kernel = np.ones((111,111), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# invert so rectangle is white
morph = 255 - morph

# get largest contour and draw on copy of input
result = img.copy()
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
cv2.drawContours(result, [big_contour], 0, (255,255,255), 1)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("black_rectangle_outline_thresh.png", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("black_rectangle_outline_morph.png", morph)
cv2.imwrite("black_rectangle_outline_result.png", result)

# display results
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("MORPH", morph)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Morphology Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution!